# How to precede some keys before going to visual mode?

Tags: vim

I want to mark current cursor position before going to visual mode. I think I could do this:

```
vmap v mlv " hence mark the position to l and start visual mode
```

But it doesn't work. Are there other ways to do the same? Please, do not suggest to map this action to \v or to anything else, I just want to learn how to "rewrite" default key mappings.

Comment: The answers to all your questions can be found in Vim's extensive documentation. Use it. And your brain.

Comment: I've already use it and use it heavily! But in this case I just mix them up (vmap/nmap). So nothing special here) I think I need a rest)

Comment: Search vim's help for `<` register. I think it will mark the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vmap` is used to create a mapping that is usable from within visual mode. `nmap` is used to create a mapping that is usable from within normal mode. However, if you were to use `nmap`, Vim would go into an infinite loop since `v` within your `mlv` will be self-referencing.

Hence, you should use `nnoremap` for a non-recursive normal mapping.

```
nnoremap v mlv
```